# Avoidable padding with "unfull" structs

Tags: c

I was trying to give a "logical" counter-example to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20019106/912144) indicating that sorting the members of a struct based on their size would minimize padding, when I encountered what seems to me as illogical.

Imagine the following struct:

```
struct A
{
    int32_t a;
    int16_t b;
};
```

`sizeof` this struct would normally be padded to 8 bytes to make sure `a` is aligned for example in an array of `struct A`.

Now image these other structs:

```
struct B
{
    struct A a, b;
    int16_t c, d;
};

struct C
{
    struct A a;
    int16_t c;
    struct A b;
    int16_t d;
};
```

As expected `struct B` has size 20 due to padding. However, I would have expected `struct C` to have size 16 since padding *could* be avoided, but [ideone](http://ideone.com/60MYwG) and gcc (with or without optimization) give a size of 24 bytes, clearly padding 2 bytes after each of the members.

My reasoning is that `struct A` in reality has only 6 bytes and should be padded when necessary, for example in an array of `struct A` or its usage in `struct B`. However, in `struct C` padding of `struct A` is unnecessary and `c` could have been placed where the padding of `a` could have been and the same with `d` and `b`.

Why doesn't the compiler minimize the padding by putting `c` where the padding of `a` would be?

---

P.S. I understand that `sizeof(struct A)` must return 8. Otherwise something like `memset(array_of_A, 0, N * sizeof *array_of_A)` won't work properly since `array_of_A` would contain padding while `N * sizeof *array_of_A` would ignore that padding.

The only thing I can think of that could be a problem is that with the optimization above then `sizeof(struct C)` would be *smaller* than the `sizeof` of all its members. However, I can't think of a case where such a thing could become a problem (i.e. a usage that is not based on undefined behavior).

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but I think what you are asking would require sizeof() to return different values on the same type. For example, sizeof(foo.A) to be different then sizeof(struct A). So copying these things would be really difficult.

Comment: Why doesn't it rearrange the members? Because the C compiler was not designed to do so in the first place. It's arranged in the order you declare them. C is a fairly low-level language giving us more control over many things, it would be bad if the compiler changed things around. If I declared members `A`, `B` and `C`, I would expect them to be laid out in memory in that order.

Comment: @CharlieBurns, My last paragraph was trying to address that. `sizeof(foo.a)` wouldn't need to be different from `sizeof(struct A)`. Sure if `sizeof(foo.a)` returns 8, then it contains `foo.c` in its padding, but you can't access that part since its outside the struct and accessing it would be undefined behavior. So, what would be the problem if `sizeof(foo.a)` returns 8?

Comment: @JeffMercado, I'm not asking the compiler to reorder the members. The standard specifically forbids that (C11, 6.7.2.1.6)

Comment: Wouldn't memcpy(&someC.a, &someA, sizeof(someC.a)) write over someC.c? I guess that's the same as the answer, and what I was getting at with my comment.

Comment: @CharlieBurns, you are right. This is a more robust counter example than the answer! I'll accept it if you right it in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memcpy(&someC.a, &someA, sizeof(someC.a))` would write over `someC.c`.

That's what I was trying to get at with my comment about `sizeof()`'s having
to be different. For that `memcpy()` to work, `sizeof(someC.a)` would have to
be different from `sizeof(someA)` which just seems to be asking for a lot of
trouble and hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct C someC;
struct A someA;
*(struct A*)&(someC.a) = someA;
```

The assignment above may fail (mistakenly write to `someC.c`) if the padding you describe is supported by compilers.

**EDITED:** The example above relies on the compiler behavior when assigning structs. As I have known (an just checked) `gcc` copies as the struct is a flat region of memory, which is not member-wise.

**EDITED:** Changed from "would fail" to "may fail" since it's not defined if the padding bits shall be copied, see item 6 of section 6.2.6.1 of ISO_IEC_9899_2011:

> When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member
>   object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to any padding bytes take
>   unspeciﬁed values.51)

and footnote `51)`:

> 51) Thus, for example, structure assignment need not copy any padding bits.

Comment: sizeof(someC.a) == sizeof(someA)

Comment: That's a pitfall, correct. It seams that the standard could have excluded the padding in the end and define that that padding shouldn't be copied. But I guess that would have probably introduced an unnecessary restriction.

Comment: I'm accepting the other answer since it presents an example that unconditionally breaks.